# Cant connect database on xampp

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna try to develop simple web page by using xampp server.this is my html coding

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="registration2.php" method="post">
id: <input type="text" name="id">
pass: <input type="text" name="pass">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my php coding to connect to the server and receive information from html form.my database name is project and my table name is registration.attributes on my table are reg_id,reg_pass,reg_email.

```
  <?php

 //the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form
 mysql_connect("localhost","user_name","password");//database connection
 mysql_select_db("project");

 // Get values from form 
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

  //inserting data order
 $order = "INSERT INTO registration
   (reg_id, reg_pass,reg_email)
  VALUES
   ('$id','$pass','$email')";

 //declare in the order variable
 $result = mysql_query($order); //order executes
 if($result)
{
 echo("
Input data is succeed");
}
 else
{
 echo("
 Input data is fail");
}

?>
```

I got error.i cant connect to mysql.the result doesnt show up.can someone show me where i'm wrong?sry for my bad english.

Comment: 1) Add error handling: `mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error())`. 2) stop working on this code and learn about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), 3) stop using the obsolete/deprecated mysql_*() functions.

Comment: Look into PDO as an alternative. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.


As for your question: have you started both apache and mysql in xammp?

Comment: i already started apache and mysql on xampp

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user_name","password")or die('could not connect'.mysql_error()); //database connection
 mysql_select_db("project",$con);

//all other lines
$order = "INSERT INTO registration
(reg_id, reg_pass,reg_email)
VALUES
('$id','$pass','$email')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);
if(!$result) {
die();}
```

Comment: still got the same error.i cant connect to my database.

Comment: i cant connect to my database.this statement 'Input data is succeed");
}
 else
{
 echo("
 Input data is fail");
}  doesnt show up.